Why is the translational motion left out of the energy eigenvalue in the hydrogen atom?
When solving the hydrogen atom, since we have two particles, the wave function has the form $\psi(\mathbf{q}_1,\mathbf{q}_2)$. Generally, textbooks proceed to demonstrate that an interacting two-particle problem can be transformed into two one-particle problems without interaction. I briefly describe the idea.
Let $\mathbf{r}_1$ denote the position of the electron and $\mathbf{r}_2$ the position of the nucleus. The position of the nucleus with respect to the electron, and the position of the center of mass with respect to the origin are
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1 \qquad
  \mathbf{C} = \frac{m_1\mathbf{r}_1 + m_2\mathbf{r}_2}{m_1 + m_2} \tag{1,2}
\end{equation}
Eqs. (1,2) can be seen as a system of two equations with two unknowns, but in vector form. Straight algebra leads to the transformation
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{r}_1 = \mathbf{C} - \frac{m_2}{m_1 + m_2}\mathbf{r}  \qquad
  \mathbf{r}_2 = \mathbf{C} + \frac{m_1}{m_1 + m_2}\mathbf{r} \tag{3,4}
\end{equation}
Using Eqs. (3,4) we can calculate the classical kinetic energy of two these two particles, which after some algebra leads to
\begin{equation}
  T = \frac{1}{2}m_1\bigg\vert\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_1}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\vert^2 +
      \frac{1}{2}m_2\bigg\vert\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_2}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\vert^2 \to
  T = {\frac{1}{2}M\bigg\vert\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{C}}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\vert^2} +
      \frac{1}{2}\mu\bigg\vert\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\vert^2 \tag{5}
\end{equation}
where $M \equiv m_1 + m_2$ is the total mass and $\mu \equiv m_1m_2/(m_1 + m_2)$ is the reduced mass. We can sum to this expression the potential energy which is a function only of $\mathbf{r}$. The quantum-mechanical Hamiltonian is
\begin{equation}
  \hat{H} =
  \color{blue}{\frac{\hat{p}_M^2}{2M}} +
  \color{red}{\left[\frac{\hat{p}_\mu^2}{2\mu} - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r}\right]}
\end{equation}
The blue part is only function of the coordinates of $\mathbf{C}$ and related to the translational motion, whereas the red part only a function of the coordinates of $\mathbf{r}$ and related to the internal motion (vibration + rotation). We have obtained an equivalent system of two non-interacting particles: one with an hypothetical mass $M$, and the other with an hypothetical mass $\mu$. In addition, we know that

The wave function of the system is the product of both wave functions.
The total energy of the system is the sum of both energies.

The solutions for the red Hamiltonian are the hydrogen wave functions, i.e. $R_{nl}(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$ and the energies are the famous $E_n = -k/n^2$. For the blue Hamiltonian we need to solve
\begin{equation}
  -\frac{\hbar^2}{2M}\nabla^2\psi_\mathrm{M} = E_\mathrm{M}\psi_\mathrm{M} \tag{6}
\end{equation}
This is the quantum-mechanical problem of the free particle in 3D, which we can solve by separation of variables. Doing this method and defining $E_\mathrm{M} \equiv E_\mathrm{M,X} + E_\mathrm{M,Y} + E_\mathrm{M,Z}$ we just get the product of three wave functions
\begin{align}
\psi_\mathrm{M}(X,Y,Z) =&
 \left[A_Xe^{-i\sqrt{2ME_\mathrm{M,X}}X/\hbar} + B_Xe^{i\sqrt{2ME_\mathrm{M,X}}X/\hbar}\right] \\
&\left[A_Ye^{-i\sqrt{2ME_\mathrm{M,Y}}Y/\hbar} + B_Ye^{i\sqrt{2ME_\mathrm{M,Y}}Y/\hbar}\right] \\
&\left[A_Ze^{-i\sqrt{2ME_\mathrm{M,Z}}Y/\hbar} + B_Ze^{i\sqrt{2ME_\mathrm{M,Z}}Z/\hbar}\right]
  \tag{7}
\end{align}
where we denoted with $X,Y,Z$ the the vector which goes from the origin to the center of mass. The real energy of the hydrogen atom would be
\begin{equation}
  E = \color{green}{-\frac{\mu e^4}{8\varepsilon_0^2h^2n^2}} +
  E_\mathrm{M,X} + E_\mathrm{M,Y} + E_\mathrm{M,Z}
  \tag{8}
\end{equation}
Even though the free particle has a wave function, is not well-behaved in the sense that they diverge as $X,Y,Z \to \pm\infty$, as the they are linear combinations of sine and cosine functions. In other words, they are not normalizable. Generally, in quantum chemistry we disregard wave functions that are not well-behaved, so being practical we would just leave them out of the problem and stick with the solution given by the red Hamiltonian, so only the green part in Eq. (8) remains. Another practical argument would be that this part is enough to correlate the spectroscopy measurements for the hydrogen spectrum.
However, I am unable to find a source that says something about this additional part. Why are the energies $E_\mathrm{M}$'s left out? If they should not be left out, how would it be possible to calculate them since they are coming from wave functions which are not quadratically integrable?

The internal potential $e^2/r$ is not coupled to the overall translational kinetic energy so these are in effect two different problems and we can choose the translational kinetic energy to be anything we want without effecting the internal motion.

@porphyrin Hi porphyrin. I ask you the following, then. Say you want to evaluate the frequency $\nu_{1 \to 2}$ due to the hydrogen atom going from state $n = 1$ to $n = 2$. How would you apply Eq. (8), then? Does the energy of the translational motion remain unchanged?

yes unchanged, otherwise we would not observe spectral lines but wide continuous blobs due to the range of kinetic energies, i.e no discrete spectra at all. (There is of course Doppler broadening but that is a different effect to your proposal)

@porphyrin That was what I thought... but none of the textbooks stated that (maybe it was obvious). Feel free to write an answer, which I'd gladly accept. Thanks!
